# Storyboard scene not binding with ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, viewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

As the question suggests, I have a storyboard scene, which isn't binding with the corresponding ViewController class. I have changed the class name by selecting the file's owner and coupled all the widgets with the corresponding variables in the class. Even after this, the binding doesn't seem to be happening - the IBAction methods aren't firing, the UIImageViews aren't being assigned the right images and so on. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

P.S. - This scene is opened from another using a modal segue. (If that is helpful)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your only problem here is that you didn't change the class properly your scene is referring to. Double check by:

1. Selecting your view controller scene in `storyboard`
2. In the identity inspector change the default class name to your `custom view controller name`

Also since you are presenting your scene through a modal segue, i would check you have correctly set your identifier of your storyboard segue. Click on your segue in storyboard then check this value under `Attributes Inspector -> Storyboard Segue -> Identifier`

Comment: I've already done this. I've changed the name of the Custom class field to my custom ViewController name. Then, I coupled all the class buttons, images, etc to the ones on my scene. Even then it doesn't work.

Comment: How are u presenting your modal segue? check my edit: this might be related to your storyboard segue identifier

Comment: You are right, the field is empty. I am not sure what value I should assign to it. Please tell me. And is this the same as a Storyboard ID?

Comment: No it is different than Storyboard ID. This identifier corresponds to the ID you will provide when invoking the method performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: Does this mean I have to explicitly open this scene programmatically in addition to the setup in the storyboard?

Comment: It depends: you can have both approaches. I usually take the pro grammatically approach but that is not necessarily needed. What is your modal segue linked to? a button or a view?

Comment: I linked the segue to a view from a button.

Comment: This should be fine then. So none of your views from the modal scene are being loaded or only partially?

Comment: Some are being loaded. The UIImageView in the scene is not being set by the imageWithName function, plus there is a button which doesn't fire the corresponding IBAction function when clicked. The viewDidLoad function IS running though. Its only the views which are causing the problem somehow.

Comment: Also, is it a problem if there are two segues from the same scene but from different buttons? This is the case here. But the thing is, the other segue works fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21828/discussion-between-tiguero-and-rameez-hussain)